# Phonegap VideoJS Android 4.0 + Not working

Tags: android, cordova, video, phonegap-plugins, video.js

I would just like to have a confirmation or a good discussion on the reason why Video tag is very much useless for Phonegap Applications on Android 4.0 and above and Lolipop.

I am using Cordova 5.0 or better to say Phonegap 4.0 and I integrated both **Video JS** and a **normal video tag**. I have included the Video JS library, it's required CSS and fonts.

My Code looks some what like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/video-js.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/videojs/video.js"></script>
```

And I have added 2 VideoJS initialised tags as well as 2 normal tags with 1 online source and 1 locally embedded source:

To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video

```
    local

    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none"
           poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
           data-setup="{}">
        <source src="libs/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
    </video>

    net

    <video controls src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">


    </video>

    local

    <video controls src="libs/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">


    </video>
```

But the problem is **none of the 4 videos play**. They appear to be completely buggy.

Below is the screenshot on Lolipop:

[image: Screenshot of how VideoJS tag appears]

[image: Screenshot of how normal Video tag appears]

[image: Screenshot of VideoJS tag when playing sources from internet and locally.]

[image: Screenshot of how normal video tag appears when clicked play button]

This is a real pinning issue as I do not understand when the webkits of phonegap and normal android browser are same then why such issue is arising. It basically makes the video tag feature of HTML5 useless and hence principle of phonegap of having the same business logic across.

Is there any solution available to this? Or is it a known cordova issue.

Thanks,
Ankit Tanna

Comment: On a side note - Yesterday I was trying to create a .apk from a swf file, I was using a webview to load all this. Things have certainly changed - there is no flash support. a lot of tags which enable plugins have been deprecated - to such an extent that methods have been removed.

Comment: Clearly, I am way too distant from Flash and SWF! Pure HTML5. Yes, there have been a lot of changes.